# MYSQL: Select and order users table by matching values, but separate column names?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check and order my users table who has the most origins (referals).

I have a users table, which has an 'origin' column, filled in with another users 'username' column if they refereed them, null if nobody.

Here is what I have so far, but its constantly returning 0 for the `origin_count` column?

```
SELECT username, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM users 
     WHERE origin = username) AS origin_count 
FROM users 
WHERE tmp_allow_share = 1 AND approved_at IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Typo at "origin = usernane"?

Comment: @Burrito origin is the correct column name.

Comment: Is `usernane` also correct column name or should it be `username`?

Comment: @AAA Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: @zedfoxus no that is a typo I've corrected the issue. I can confirm it is correct in my DB IDE.

Comment: @Progman I believe I have narrowed it down to a specific issue, `origin_count` is returning 0 regardless of if it has origins.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE origin = username` counts how many users have themselves as origin.

Comment: How does one change this so that it checks the entire table count? I have protection in place to ensure you can't be your own origin but I want to count how many other users have each user and order by the most. I was under the impression this was a subquery and would run outside of the main query and check the entire table.

Comment: Use table aliases to distinguish the `users` table in the main query and in the subquery.

Comment: _"I have a users table, which has an 'origin' column, filled in with another users 'username' column if they refereed them, null if nobody."_ where's that sample data? Now, make use of this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86e5c33c0cce832c2cc26552e8d7458f . Insert your sample data and post it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE origin = username` counts how many users have themselves as origin.

What you want to do is group by username and count origin (possibly distinct if you're looking for unique referals).

```
SELECT COUNT(origin) FROM users GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery to calculate origin count, rather use `count` directly with `group by`

```
SELECT username,
   count(*) AS origin_count
FROM users
WHERE tmp_allow_share = 1
  AND approved_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY username;
```